# How to add jquery in specific width

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, skrollr

I am using skroller.js. But after using this jquery, Touch is not working on the mobile version of my site.

Comment: Can you explain in details what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I am using skroller.js. But after using this jquery. Touch is not woking on mobile version.

Comment: Please add this to your question and also add tags like skroller.js and mobile

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

Check this DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/aq5vb/4/

Try to resize the result frame see what happens when the window's size reaches 960px.

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    doThisScript();
});

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    doThisScript();
});

function doThisScript() {
    $('.content').html('Your current width is '+$(window).width());
    
    if($(window).width() >= '960'){
        // add your scripts here
        $('.content').css({'background':'green'});
    }    
    else{
        $('.content').css({'background':'white'});
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add js after this line.
"if($(window).width() >= '960'){".

Comment: Yes, try this. If the window size is 960 or larger, your script will/should run.

Comment: Ya i already use this. Its working. But i don't know how to add jQuery after if condition.

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong in this code.<script>
 if(jQuery( window ).width() > '768' ) {
  wp_register_script('skrollr_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.min.js', false, 0.1);
  wp_enqueue_script('skrollr_script');  
 }
 </script>. It's showing this error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Comment: Like this => if ($(window).width() >= '960') {
        wp_register_script('skrollr_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/skrollr.min.js', false, 0.1);
        wp_enqueue_script('skrollr_script');
        
    }